# Secure Wordpress - File Permissions

Tags: wordpress

I want to secure wordpress by now allowing any files to be edited (I will manually just update wordpress). What should I set the folders as?

wp-content = 755
everything else = 644

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Hardening WordPress](http://codex.wordpress.org/Hardening_WordPress) on the [WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/) is a very good article on how to secure your WordPress blog, which goes into quite some detail on file permissions, as well as some other methods of securing WP.